# Android getContentResolver insert not returning full URI

Tags: insert, uri, android-contentprovider

I have an activity that is being swapped out when I raise an intent for another activity.  onPause calls saveState() to save work so far:

```
private void saveState() {
    ...
    ...
    if (myUri == null) {
        // Inserting a new record
*** myUri = getContentResolver().insert(ContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
    } else {
        // Update an existing record
        getContentResolver().update(myUri, values, null, null);
    }
}
```

Before calling getContentResolver(), ContentProvider.CONTENT_URI = 'content://nz.co.bkd.extraTime.contentprovider/times'.

After the call, myUri = 'times/#' where #=row ID. My question is; where is the 'content:...' prefix to the returned uri?

During the call, ContentResolver.java is called and returns CreatedRow uri

```
ContentResolver.java
....
....
public final Uri insert(Uri url, ContentValues values)
{
    IContentProvider provider = acquireProvider(url);
    if (provider == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + url);
    }
    try {
        long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
***     Uri createdRow = provider.insert(url, values);
        long durationMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        maybeLogUpdateToEventLog(durationMillis, url, "insert", null /* where */);
        return createdRow;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // Arbitrary and not worth documenting, as Activity
        // Manager will kill this process shortly anyway.
        return null;
    } finally {
        releaseProvider(provider);
    }
}
```

At this point, createdRow = 'times/#'.

The record does actually get saved in the Sqlite database.

Do I have to add the uri prefix in my code or should the full uri be returned?

Comment: It seems that is what the content provider is returning. Do you have access to content provider's code ?